# Способы обмена информацией между Service и Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, service, activity

Как правильно организовать обмен данными между `Service` и `Activity`?

Собственно из `Activity` в `Service` данные отправить не проблема. А вот как, например, из `Service` обновить `View`, который контролирует `Activity`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Насвкидку 4 варианта обмена `Service <-> Activity`:

1. Обмен параметрами `Parcelable` при запуске `Service` из `Activity` и наоборот, но, увы, это можно сделать только 1 раз - при запуске.
2. Через механизм [Service binding](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) - связывания `Activity` и `Service` - в итоге можно иметь в `Activity` указатель на экземпляр службы.
3. Через [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html).
4. Через [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) - по сути, запуск в `Service` собственного обработчика сообщений.

P.S. В вашем случае наиболее работоспособный вариант либо 3, либо 4. 4-й подходит больше (мне кажется).

Comment: Спасибо! Нашел неплохой пример про Handler с разъяснениеями, если кому интересно    
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594936/communication-between-activity-and-service    
Также мне понравился способ eventBus от @gcoder.

Answer (score 10):

Еще можно юзать [Otto](https://github.com/square/otto) или [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Answer (score 6):

Хотел бы добавить более продвинутый вариант обмена событиями с помощью RxJava, а именно такую штуку, как [RxBus](https://github.com/kaushikgopal/RxJava-Android-Samples/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/morihacky/android/rxjava/rxbus/RxBus.java). Суть, в принципе, та же, что и в Otto или EventBus, но гораздо удобнее и более гибко. Особенно если вы используете RxJava в проекте — не потребуется добавлять ещё одну зависимость. Тем более скорость работы на RxBus должна быть выше.

Ещё одна очень удобная вещь - RxBus с возможностью получить последнее актуальное событие, вне зависимости, была ли активность подписана на это событие в момент «излучения» этого события. 
Вот небольшой пример на Котлине, не бойтесь этого кода. Всё отличие в том, что используется BehaviourSubject, который и позволяет получить последнее событие.

```
import rx.lang.kotlin.BehaviourSubject
import rx.subjects.BehaviorSubject

object RxBehaviorBus {

  private val bus: BehaviorSubject<Any> = BehaviourSubject<Any>()

  fun send(any: Any) {
    bus.onNext(any)
  }

  fun toObservable() = bus
}
```