# Как закрыть другое Activity из класса, наследующего Service?

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, service

Мой класс `MyService`:

```
public class MyService extends Service
{
    IBinder mBinder;
    public static boolean status = true;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        someTask();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        Log.e("MY_SERVICE", "onDestroy()");
        new CheckThread().stop();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public void someTask()
    {
        new CheckThread().start();
    }

    public class CheckThread implements Runnable
    {
        Thread th;

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            main();
        }

        public void start()
        {
            th = new Thread(this);
            th.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
            Log.e("CheckThread", "start()");
            th.start();
        }

        public synchronized void stop()
        {
            th = null;
            status = false;
            Log.e("CheckThread", "stop()");
            notify();
        }

        public void main()
        {
            while (status)
            {
                if ( ! status)
                    stop();
                boolean connect = Vars.connect;
                if ( ! connect)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                    intent.setClass(MyService.this, Disconnect.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    status = false;
                    stop();
                }
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Класс `Disconnect` запускается, когда закрывается `Socket`-соединение (класс не наследует `Activity`, функции с UI недоступны).

```
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            String str = "";
            try
            {
                while ((str = in.readLine()) != null)
                {

                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
            }
            Vars.connect = false;
        }
    }).start();
```

Возможно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы при открытии класса `Disconnect` в `MyService` закрывалось другое активное `Activity`, чтобы был активен только `Disconnect`?

Ответов, как закрыть другое `Activity` из класса, наследующего `Service`, я не нашёл.

Answer (score 6):

Только сама `Activity` может завершить себя (также она может быть завершена ОС).

Из `Service` надо послать сигнал `Activity` на завершение, по получении которого она сама вызовет `finish()`. Сделать это можно одним из способов, описанных в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/356859#356865) ответе.

Лично я рекомендую [`LocalBroadcastManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html).