# Обмен данными между service и listView.adapter или recyclerview.adapter

Tags: android, listview, service, android-viewpager, adapter

Господа, у меня есть Service, в нем я получаю события из сервера в реальном времени.

**Вопрос**

Как установить связь между Adapter и Service ? В Activity подключаться с помощью ServiceConnection, и из Adapter передавать в Activity себя? 
Ну типо

```
getActivity().setAdater(this);
```

Или есть другие способы? Просто если бы ListView был в Activity, было бы проще, а так у меня ViewPager, и списки там, и как все это правильно сделать я не знаю.

Comment: Попробуйте пользоваться поиском, говорят, что это помогает быстрее решить проблему, избежать дублирования вопросов, экономит ваше время и мои нервы.
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/356859/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-service-%D0%B8-activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут есть много вариантов. По сути передать данные из сервиса в активити можно 3 методами: PendingIntent, BroadcastReceiver и через биндинг.

Я так полагаю у вас во ViewPager используются фрагменты. 
Взять текущий фрагмент из ViewPager тоже не проблема, и передать данные из Активити во фрагмент тоже не проблема.

В данном случае наверно проще всего в нужном фрагмента зарегистрировать программно `BroadcastReceiver` и слать из сервиса бродкасты.