# Как сделать сервис GPSTracker?

Tags: java, android

Написал приложение, которое определяет местоположение по GPS/WiFi(мобильным сетям), показывает на карте в виде метки, записывает координаты в базу данных SQLite, а затем можно просматривать треки перемещений за день. Но, приложение работает только когда экран активен.
Возникла потребность сделать так, чтобы определение координат и запись их в БД работало в фоне(экран не активен, приложение свернуто и т.п.)

В MainActivity оставил инициализацию карты, рисование треков и прочее, типа определения переменных и т.п.
В Service перенес запрос на определение местоположение через LocationManager, получение самих координат и запись их в БД.

Собственно вопрос:

1. Как передать myPostition, т.е. latitude и longitude, из метода getLocation сервиса в MainActivity, чтобы потом их можно было поместить на карту в виде маркера?
2. Правильно ли я сделал, что поместил запрос на обновление локации(местоположения) в onStartCommand? Или это нужно было сделать в onCreate() сервиса?

Вот примерный код:

```
public class TrackerService extends Service implements LocationListener {

final String myLog = "my_Logs";
LocationManager locationManager;
double latitude, longitude;
LatLng myPosition;
Calendar addTimeCalendar;
String addDate;
Cursor c = null;

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(myLog, "onStartCommand");
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1000 * 60, 25, this);
    Log.d(myLog, "GPS_Provider request location updates");
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000 * 60, 25, this);
    Log.d(myLog, "Network_Provider request location updates");
    //getLocation(location);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    getLocation(location);
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    getLocation(locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider));
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    checkEnabled();
}

public void getLocation(final Location location) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (location == null)
                return;
            if (location.getProvider().equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                Log.d(myLog, "GPS Provider Enabled");
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                myPosition = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
                addCoordinates();
                Log.d(myLog, "---GPS Координаты добавлены---");
            } else if (location.getProvider().equals(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
                Log.d(myLog, "NETWORK PROVIDER Enabled");
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                myPosition = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
                addCoordinates();
                Log.d(myLog, "---Network Координаты добавлены---");
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

public void addCoordinates() {
    addTimeCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat addDayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    addDate = addDayFormat.format(addTimeCalendar.getTime());
    SQL sqlHelper = new SQL(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = sqlHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    Log.d(myLog, "--- Insert in coordinates: ---");
    cv.put("Latitude", latitude);
    cv.put("Longitude", longitude);
    cv.put("Time", addDate);
    long rowID = db.insert("coordinates", null, cv);
    Log.d(myLog, "row inserted, ID = " + rowID);
    db.close();
    sqlHelper.close();
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(myLog, "onDestroy");
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
```

}

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/356859/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-service-%D0%B8-activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тебе необходимо переделать свой Service в IntentService который будет отсылать Intent'ы содержащие информацию о локации.

Оборачивать что-то в Thread - нет нужды так как IntentService уже работает асинхронно.

Чтобы организовать коммуникацию между сервисом и своим приложением нужно:

1. IntentService - делает всякое барахло в бэкграунде и отсылает интенты
2. BroadcastReceiver - принимает интенты
3. Зарегистрировать BroadcastReceiver в своём Activity

Пример базовой коммуникации между IntentService и Activity:

**Код в Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "ExampleActivity";
private ExampleReceiver receiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mainButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ExampleIntentService.startAction(MainActivity.this);
        }
    });

    receiver = new ExampleReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            super.onReceive(context, intent);

            if (intent != null) {

                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (action.equals(ExampleReceiver.ACTION_UPDATE)) {

                    //do what you want
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, String.format("Received %s %f | %f", action,
                            intent.getDoubleExtra(ExampleReceiver.ARG_LAT, 0),
                            intent.getDoubleExtra(ExampleReceiver.ARG_LON, 0)));
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(ExampleReceiver.ACTION_UPDATE);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
}
```

**Код IntentService:**

```
public class ExampleIntentService extends IntentService {

public static final String ACTION_START = "com.example.example.action.UPDATE";

public ExampleIntentService() {
    super("ExampleIntentService");
}

/**
 * Starts this service to perform action with the given parameters. If
 * the service is already performing a task this action will be queued.
 *
 * @see IntentService
 */
public static void startAction(Context context) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExampleIntentService.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_START);
    context.startService(intent);
}


@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    if (intent != null) {

        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_START.equals(action)) {

            //temp values
            double lat = 55.743274;
            double lon = 37.669726;
            sendUpdateLocationIntent(lat, lon);
        }
    }
}

private void sendUpdateLocationIntent(double lat, double lon) {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(ExampleReceiver.ACTION_UPDATE);
    intent.putExtra(ExampleReceiver.ARG_LAT, lat);
    intent.putExtra(ExampleReceiver.ARG_LON, lon);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
}
```

**Код BroadcastReceiver:**

```
public class ExampleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static final String ACTION_UPDATE = "com.example.example.action.UPDATE";
public static final String ARG_LAT = "com.example.example.extra.LAT";
public static final String ARG_LON = "com.example.example.extra.LON";

public ExampleReceiver() {

}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    /**
     * This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
     * an Intent broadcast.
     */
}
}
```

**PS: не забудь объявить BroadcastReceiver и IntentService в AndroidManifest:**

```
    <service
        android:name=".ExampleIntentService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name=".ExampleReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
    </receiver>
```