# Как правильно вызвать service?

Tags: java, android

Как правильно вызывать сервис в `MainActivity`, чтобы действия в методе `onStartCommand()` выполнялись постоянно?

В `onStartCommand()` находится запрос на получение местоположения через `LocationManager` и, собственно, получение их.

Если нужен код сервиса, могу добавить ниже.

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы сервис регулярно запрашивал местоположение?

Comment: @Rishka, да, записывал их в БД и передавал на MainActivity, код этого всего есть рабочий, просто вопрос в его размещении

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычно используется директива `START_STICKY` что бы сервис не останавливался. К примеру

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Но когда вы работаете с  `LocationManager` есть своя функция `onLocationChanged(Location)`  который срабатывает когда меняется местоположение.

Я бы посоветовал, запустит службу с `START_STICKY` и внутри создать `Runnable` который периодически будет проверять координаты. И служба не остановиться и на БД будет накапливаться данные.

Comment: добавил в ваш ответ код, посмотрите пожалуйста, правильно ли я вас понял.

Comment: Или вот код:

        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStartCommand");
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1000 * 60, 25, this);
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000 * 60, 25, this);

                getLocation(location);

            }

        });

        return START_STICKY;

    }

Comment: Код который вы отправили не сможет работать.Так как Runnable остановится после первого запуска. Могу предложить готовый исходный код, прочитайте думаю поможет. http://open-gpstracker.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1132/trunk/OpenGPSTracker/trunk/application/src/nl/sogeti/android/gpstracker/logger/GPSLoggerService.java

Comment: http://open-gpstracker.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1132/trunk/OpenGPSTracker/trunk/application/src/nl/sogeti/android/ вот полный рабочий проект

Comment: А что не так с тем кодом, что я добавил? Как его исправить?

Comment: В вашем коде что нужно сделать: 1) Отделить Runnable класс в отдельный файл. 2) в функции Run создать бесконечный цикл, который периодически отдыхает минут 2 и заново запрашивает координаты и сохраняет в базу 3) создайте locationManager отдельно для GPS и отдельно для NETWORK. так легче управлять обоими сервисами.

Comment: есть подобная ветка http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/426148/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81-gpstracker кажется нужно это как то вместе решить. но Ваш код с START_STICKY был правильным, но не потоки.

Comment: насколько я понимаю, код без потока будет выполняться ровно столько раз, сколько раз выполнен вызов сервиса, так?

Comment: Если поток внутри сервиса не остановится, оно будет выполнтся пока не завершится цикл. и сделайте так что бы один и тот же поток не запускался несколько раз. Сделайте static boolean переменную, и пусть цикл повторяется пока переменная истинна while (canWork) {...} и потом когда Вам захочется остановит цикл, сделаете canWork=False. и все. поток закроется сам.