# Android Service, получения сообщений в Adapter

Tags: java, android, service, adapter

Есть Service, в нем из сервера в реальном времени приходят данные, и эти данные нужно как то передать в BaseAdapter. Как это правильно сделать? В адаптере зарегистрировать BroadcastReceiver ? Или есть другие способы?

Например в Service пришло новое сообщение, это сообщение мне нужно передать в мой адаптер, и показать его пользователю. И как же мне это сообщения из Service, передать в адаптер?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/356859/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-service-%D0%B8-activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) и [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html).
В сервисе пишите в базу, по средствам `contentprovider`, `adapter` наследуете от [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html), `cursorloader` получает сообщение о готовности данных, подтягивает их из базы и обновляет `adapter`.