# Как поставить на паузу/возобновить MediaPlayer не останавливая Service?

Tags: android

Использую `MediaPlayer` и `Service`.
Идея такая: запускать сервис один раз, а затем используя методы сервиса ставить на паузу или возобновлять воспроизведение аудио потока по ссылке.
Но при запуске приложения `MediaPlayer` выдает ошибки:

```
E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
E/MediaPlayer: start called in state 1
E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
E/MediaPlayer: start called in state 0
```

Как исправить ошибки? И можно ли вообще такое реализовать?

Код активити:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String url = "http://62.80.190.246:8000/ProstoRadiO128";
    Button mPlayPauseButton;
    boolean musicPlaying = false;
    Intent serviceIntent;
    MyService ps = new MyService();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initViews();
        initListeners();
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
                serviceIntent.putExtra("url", url);
                startService(serviceIntent);
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }

    private void initViews() {
        mPlayPauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play_pause);
        mPlayPauseButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
    }

    private void initListeners() {
        mPlayPauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                playPauseClick();
            }
        });
    }

    private void playPauseClick() {
        if (!musicPlaying) {
        ps.startStream();
        mPlayPauseButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
        musicPlaying = true;
    }
    else if (musicPlaying) {
        ps.stopStream();
        mPlayPauseButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
        musicPlaying = false;
    }
    }
}
```

Код сервиса:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    String TAG = "PlayerService__Log";
    String url;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.v(TAG, "Creating Service");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        url = intent.getStringExtra("url");
        Log.d(TAG, "url: " + url);
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(TAG, e.getClass().getName() + " " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    public void startStream() {
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    public void stopStream() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mediaPlayer.stop();
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Навскидку, скорей всего ошибка, из-за того, что Вы и запустили сервис

```
serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
```

И создали отдельный экземпляр класса     `MyService ps = new MyService();`
из-под которого вызываете методы управления `mediaPlayer`.

Comment: @Александр Простым языком вы одному сервису говорите "запустись, и возьми этот URL", а совершенно другому сервису - "Начинай играть" и "перестань играть". Второй сервис не знает, что ему играть. Посмотрите тут, как обмениваться данными между Activity и Service http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/356859/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-service-%D0%B8-activity

Comment: @metalurgus, как прикруть ко всему этому handler? Как я понимаю, его можно использовать для этого.

Comment: @Александр, прочитайте полностью вопрос и ответы, комментарии, там есть ссылки на доступное описание, как работать с `Handler`. Но я лично использую `EventBus`