# Попытка наладить общение между Activity и Service с помощью Binder-а

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-binder

Продолжение вопроса [Как поставить на паузу/возобновить MediaPlayer не останавливая Service?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/487017/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-mediaplayer-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-service/487032?noredirect=1#comment568197_487032)

Идея: запускать сервис один раз, а затем используя методы сервиса ставить на паузу или возобновлять воспроизведение аудио потока по ссылке ( либо передавать в сервис новые ссылки на аудио потоки) через `UI` часть.

Пробую использовать привязать `Service` к `Activity` с помощью `Binder`.
Проблемы остались те же:

```
E/MediaPlayer: start called in state 1
E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
```

Что делаю не так? (За источник взял инфу [отсюда](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/bound-services.html))

**ОБНОВЛЕН КОД СЕРВИСА**

**Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String url = "http://62.80.190.246:8000/ProstoRadiO128";
    Button mPlayPauseButton;
    boolean musicPlaying = false;
    Intent serviceIntent;
    MyService mService;
    boolean mBound = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initViews();
        initListeners();
        //startService(serviceIntent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("url", url);
        bindService(serviceIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        Log.d("", "mConnection: " + mConnection);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mBound) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;
        }
    }

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            MyService.MyServiceBinder binder = (MyService.MyServiceBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
            Log.d("", "in onServiceConnected: mBound = " + mBound);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };


    private void initViews() {
        mPlayPauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play_pause);
        mPlayPauseButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
    }

    private void initListeners() {
        mPlayPauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                playPauseClick();
            }
        });
    }

    private void playPauseClick() {
        if (mBound) {
            Log.d("", "mBound: " + mBound);
            mService.startStream();
            mPlayPauseButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
            musicPlaying = true;
        }
        else if (!mBound) {
            mService.stopStream();
            mPlayPauseButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
            musicPlaying = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Service:**

```
public class MyService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener{

    String TAG = "PlayerService__Log";
    String url;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private final IBinder mBinder = new MyServiceBinder();
    boolean isPrepared;

    public class MyServiceBinder extends Binder {
        MyService getService() {
            return MyService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.v(TAG, "Creating Service");
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand");

        url = intent.getStringExtra("url");
        Log.d(TAG, "url: " + url);
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(TAG, e.getClass().getName() + " " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
        Log.d(TAG, "media player started");
        isPrepared = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCompletion");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    public void startStream() {
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying() && isPrepared == true) mediaPlayer.start();
        else {
            Log.d(TAG, "media player is not prepared");
            isPrepared = false;
        }
    }

    public void stopStream() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Говорят в гугле, что вы, наверное, стартуете музыку до окончания подготовки (выполнения `prepareAsync()`). Также уточните задали ли вы разрешение на интернет в манифесте)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, в манифесте есть разрешение на инет.

Comment: Возможно дело в том, что плеер ещё не готов в момент старта. Обойти это можно с помощью слушателя готовности. Плюс, м.б. надо просто сначала указать, что играться поток будет, а потом уже адрес задавать....

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, можно подробнее про слушатель готовности?

Comment: [Доки](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnPreparedListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener)). Устанавливаете слушатель окончания и в нём ставьте флаг в сервис о готовности. Проверяйте его при попытке стартовать. Может в этом дело.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, добавил `onPreparedListener` и `onPrepared` в котором ставлю флаг о готовности. При нажатии на кнопку проверяю флаг и запускаю воспроизведение. Но флаг = `false`. Может ли быть такое, что не вызывается метод `onPrepared()`? Обновил код сервиса.