# Изменение конфигурации устройства в процессе загрузки данных по сети

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Здравствуйте!

Есть некоторый фрагмент, по нажатию кнопки на котором, запускается `AsyncTask` и начинает загружать данные из интернета. По окончанию загрузки, эти данные выводятся в `RecyclerView` этого фрагмента.

Насколько я понимаю, если в процессе работы `AsyncTask` изменится конфигурация устройства (например, ориентация экрана), то после этого, данные из `AsyncTask` мы уже не получим, так как фрагмент создастся заново.

Собственно, вопрос: как быть в подобных ситуациях?

PS. Интернет почитал, способов много, но информация как-то тяжело воспринимается и в итоге в голове получается каша. Подскажите, пожалуйста, **наиболее правильный**, с Вашей точки зрения, метод решения данной проблемы.

Спасибо!

PPS. Будет круто, если кто-нибудь приведет пример с использованием `AsyncTaskLoader`.

Comment: Вот вам стильный модный и молодёжный способ: https://habrahabr.ru/post/305478/

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спасибо за статью! Но, к сожалению, я далек от `RxJava`. Возможно, пришло время попробовать :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Наиболее правильным способом я считаю вынесение работы с сетью в сервис. Сервис (правильно настроенный и запущенный) не умрет при изменении конфигурации. А отобразить данные, полученные в сервисе, на View можно любым из этих способов:   [Способы обмена информацией между Service и Activity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/356859/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-service-%D0%B8-activity)