# android:Взаимодействие Service и UI

Tags: android, service

Подскажите наиболее простую, надежную и наиболее "синхронную" схему взаимодействия Компонента с GUI и Service. В ИНЕТЕ описано много схем, но, как правило, описывается схема, где главный - компонент с GUI , а SERVICE - подчиненный компонент. То есть Компонент с GUI отдает команды в Service- а Service отвечает и выполняет задачи. А тут оба компонента как бы равнозначны. Service, взаимодействует с Интернет-сервером,  передает данные в компонент с GUI для отображения(при этом данные часто меняются и должны быть максимально синхронизированы). При этом, компонент с GUI сам может инициировать ряд задач для SERVICE(который передаст данные на сервер - оттуда получит ответ и передаст их обратно в компонент с GUI для отображения данных). Такая схема требуется для того,чтобы Service мог работать в фоновом режиме даже без компонента с GUI.
Итак, требуются полноценная двунаправленная связь SERVICE и компонента с GUI с надежной синхронизацией данных(фактически в SERVICE будут храниться данные, постоянно обновляемые, а отображаться они будут в компоненте с GUI)

Comment: Да что здесь такого .В андроиде есть Context ,добавив его в контруктор или агрумент метода можете легко взаимодействовать с помощью бесконечного цикла Шэдуля

Comment: Можно чуть подробнее - идеальна была бы схема доступа к GUI из SERVICE -это вроде невозможно - или можно это организовать с помощью Context?

Comment: Как невозможно?)у Сервиса есть  Context а значит можно в коструктор ставить данные или в метод)допустим вот тебе рабочий пример из моего кода

Comment: Sender sr= new Sender(GetApplicationContext(),name,status,id,version,time);             sr.execute

Comment: Из сервиса передаю данные в MainActivity и там извлекаю их и опа )Ничего сложного

Comment: А если данные изменяются в Servis классе просто посылаете их  с интервалом допустим 5-10 секунд )

Comment: Главное основной поток не грузите ю

Comment: Из сервиса передаете данные с помощью BroadcastReciever, startActvity или как ? Меня интересует наиболее простая схема, так как Service сам взаимодействует по Websocket с сервером - то есть там нужна схема синхронизации, а тут еще и синхронизация с компонентом GUI. Как это все синхронизировать - понятно - но получается очень сложно. Поэтому меня бы устроил Binding в "обратную сторону" - то есть когда Service мог бы использовать методы компонента с GUI- такое можно реализовать?

Comment: возможно да конечно ю

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите на [мой древний ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/356859/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-service-%D0%B8-activity/356865#356865) на эту тему

В вашем случае, я бы рекомендовал обратить пристальное внимание на  п. 2 той рекомендации:

> Через механизм [Service binding](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) - связывания Activity и Service - в итоге можно иметь в Activity указатель на экземпляр службы.

На всякие новомодные Otto/EventBus не советую вестись, поскольку они не работают когда сервис находится в другом процессе.

**Update**

Если речь идет о доступе из `Service` к `Activity` в том контексте, который обсуждается в комментариях, то я бы рекомендовал способ №3

> Через [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)

Говоря русским языком при получении неких данных, которые требуют отражения в `Activity` вы посылаете `LocalBroadcast`, который ловится вашим `Activity`, вытаскиваются данные из `Bundle` упакованных в `LocalBroadcast` ну и т.д.

В принципе, можно воспользоваться и обычным Broadcast'ом, просто `LocalBroadcast`, не пересекает границы приложения за счет чего обеспечивается и скорость и приватность данных.

Comment: Идеальным вариантом был бы Binding "наоборот" - то есть чтобы SERVICE имел доступ к методам GUI компонента, так как GUI компонент больше пассивен, чем активен(в основном предназначен для отображения приходящих извне данных). Проблема в том ,что данные сложны- условно говоря - списки, из которых надо то удалять отдельные элементы, то прибавлять новые, то есть могут возникнуть проблемы с синхронизацией

Comment: Увы нет биндинга наоборот и его не может быть, потому что `Activity` постоянно независимо от `Service` то умирает то рождается заново. Так что смотрите на апдейт ответа

Comment: Понятно. Насколько по вашему связь через LocalBroadcast будет быстрее и лучше схемы: startActivity для передачи данных в GUI и startService для передачи данных в сервис -ловля сообщений через onStartCommand?.

Comment: Здесь дело даже не в скорости, а в том, что передача ч/з `startActivity()/startService()` работает только 1 раз при запуске `Activity/Service`, а у вас задача организовать взаимодейтсвие с уже работающим `Activity`.

Comment: Я не профи, но Вы вроде бы ошибаетесь - startActivity/Service всегда передают данные (если служба / активность не запущена - то запускают их).

Comment: @Barmaley не совсем так. Всякий раз вызывая startService у запущенного сервиса будет вызван onStartCommand, вполне себе метод передачи данных.

Comment: Не будет ли потеря во времени и ресурсах? Типа системе нужно проверять запущена ли активность/сервис - вопрос к Yura Ivanov

Comment: Запуск сервиса, в отличие от биндинга, возможен из любой точки программы (если есть контекст). Да, при этом запуск идет с помощью инфраструктуры андроида и если вам важны миллисекунды, которые при этом теряются, и при этом вызовы идут из одного места, используйте биндинг.

Comment: Кроме того, не стоит рассматривать запуск активити, это к вопросу отношения не имеет (хотя вы также можете запускать ее через singletop/task, например, с передачей параметров... проблема в том, что вы обяжете активити отобразиться таким образом, это не всегда верное поведение). Обратное общение можно реализовывать любым удобным для вас методом. И в этом ответе и в предыдущем (ссылка есть в ответе) варианты даны... Можно еще добавить про OrderedBroadcast (который через LocalBroadcastManager, afaik не работает), который позволит кроме прочего узнать было ли доставлено сообщение.

Comment: Находясь в инфраструктуре андроида, нечего сетовать на то, что приходится пользоваться его средствами. startService, sendBroadcast - легальные и простые механизмы.