# Как получать уведомление из HostApduService?

Tags: android, activity, service, nfc

Есть класс унаследованный от `HostApduService`(далее `NfcService`) и `Activity` которое которое что то делает. Когда у `NfcService` вызывается `processCommandApdu` происходит обработка пришедших данных и требуется в `Activity` отреагировать как то на эти данные в зависимости от них. на текущий момент есть триггер только на одно событие - изменение `SharedPreferences`. То есть `NfcService` сохраняет в `SharedPreferences` какое либо значение, а `Activity` реализует `SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` (+подписка, отписка) и соотвественно при изменении нужного параметра ключа как то реагирует.
Есть какой либо более корректный способ для такого случая реагировать на данные? Возможно сделать зависимыми `Activity` и `NfcService` (с учетом особенностей жизненного цикла `HostApduService` как такового) или рассылать Broadcast а в Activity перехватывать?

Имеется корректный способ вызова этого сервиса из activity для его последующего биндинга или передачи parcelable параметра?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Способы обмена информацией между Service и Activity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/356859/%d0%a1%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-service-%d0%b8-activity)

Comment: @eugeneek вы имеете представление о работе HostApduService? Если да, то имеется корректный способ вызова этого сервиса из activity для его последующего биндинга или передачи parcelable параметра?