# Отправить данные в уже открытый socket

Tags: android, сокет

Есть такой класс:

```
public class TCPClient {
private String serverMessage;
public static final String SERVERIP = "192.168.0.20";
public static final int SERVERPORT = 6667;
private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
private boolean mRun = false;
private static final String TAG = "TestSock";


PrintWriter out;
BufferedReader in;


public TCPClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
    mMessageListener = listener;
}

public void sendMessage(String message){
    if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
        out.println(message);
        out.flush();
    }
}

public void stopClient(){
    mRun = false;
}

public void run() {

    mRun = true;
    try {
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
        Log.e(TAG, "C: Connecting...");
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
        try {
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
            Log.e(TAG, "C: Sent.");
            Log.e(TAG, "C: Done.");
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            while (mRun) {
                serverMessage = in.readLine();
                if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                    mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);
                }
                serverMessage = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "S: Error", e);
        } finally {
            socket.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "C: Error", e);
    }
}

public interface OnMessageReceived {
    public void messageReceived(String message);
}
}
```

в сервисе я запускаю подключение к серверу и слушаю сокет на предмет новых данных. Сервер соединение не рвет и ждет данные от клиента:

```
new connectTask().execute();
```

Сам connectTask:

```
public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,TCPClient> {

    @Override
    protected TCPClient doInBackground(String... message) {
        mTcpClient = new TCPClient(new TCPClient.OnMessageReceived() {
            @Override
            public void messageReceived(String message) {
                publishProgress(message);
            }
        });
        mTcpClient.run();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        Log.e(TAG, "RECV: "+values[0]);
    }
}
```

**Вопрос:**

Как сделать отправку сообщения (mTcpClient.sendMessage("MSG to Serv\r\n");) из, например, Activity так, чтобы не создавать новое socket-соединение, а закинуть в существующее (открытое)?

Comment: То есть, в итоге весь ваш вопрос сводится к [Как связать сервис и активити](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/356859/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-service-%D0%B8-activity)?

Answer (score 0):

Как я понимаю, у вас `mTcpClient` как поле класса доступно внутири сервиса.

Значит самый явный путь, это сделать из сервиса `Bound Service`
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

т.е. сервис с интерфейсом взаимодействия. Любая активити сможет "забайндиться" и дергать методы интерфейса. В вашем случае это отправлять и если надо подписаться на сообщения.